# What is the point of interfaces and abstract classes?

Tags: java, interfaces

So I'm taking a course on java programming, and in the lesson about interfaces, they gave an example of an interface with a Bird class, along with Chicken and Sparrow subclasses that extend Bird. They wanted to give Sparrow a fly method but not chicken, and the fly method was previously in the Bird class, thus being given to both subclasses. The solution they used was to create an interface with public void fly(); in it and have Sparrow implement the interface, and then define a fly() method in the Sparrow class. This doesn't make sense, as it would have been so much easier to just define a fly() method for each type of bird that can fly and leave it at that. They never really explained why you should use an interface, as from what I gather it's just more work. Same thing with abstract classes.

Comment: Bruh why are people downvoting my post. There's nothing that people could possibly have an issue with.

Comment: The chosen example probably wasn't ideal. No need to question interfaces and abstract classes in general. But to explain would be too broad to fit in a concise answer here.

Comment: I didn't choose the example, that's just what my course used. What do you mean no need to question interfaces and abstract classes? If someone doesn't understand something, of course there's a need to question it.

Comment: This site is designed for a more mature software programming audience, i.e. generally for people who have completed the equivalent of 4 year computer science education. Students are welcome - conditionally - if they ask good quality questions. I feel pity for the quality of education you received. With the wide availability of online education materials, I hope you will find supplementary course materials. Back to the question. It is a matter of coarse-grained vs. fine-grained class interface design. You can read about the trade-offs by looking up "Interface Segregation Principle". However

Comment: ... However, some online articles that describe "Interface Segregation Principle" are pared down to the minimum, that they do not mention the trade-offs at all. Be sure to try different articles and links, and see if you can find one that explains the underlying thinking. Good luck.

Comment: @Herobrine _"If someone doesn't understand something, of course there's a need to question it."_ OK. To put it short: The point of interfaces and abstract classes is abstraction and to avoid tight coupling of concrete class implementations in larger code architectures. Does that satisfy your doubts?

Comment: It also depends on the language. The advice of splitting off interfaces may not always be the correct one. In general, an interface need to contain a cohesive set of methods (functions). If a client interaction with a class instance involves two methods, but those two methods are not found on the same interface (they are on separate interfaces), the client will have very awkward code, necessitating interface casts very often.

Comment: @rwong Well what do you expect, I'm 16. I haven't even gone to college yet, so I haven't received an education period. I'm just taking an Udemy course for fun, so I can code  Minecraft plugins on my own. Isn't the entire point of this website is for developers to receive support for problems they encounter? I don't recall hearing that you have to have gone to college and received an official education to be considered a developer.

Comment: The motivating reason for interface and abstraction is that you can write your client code once (toward / "against") an abstraction (e.g. an interface), and that client code will be applicable to different concrete implementations of that abstraction. That is, you can write something that interacts with all birds, and that piece of code will be able to interact with all concrete types (subclasses) of birds, including birds that are not known to the piece of code at the time the piece of code was written.

Comment: @Herobrine It's not my choice or opinion. Take a look at how the "crowd" (this site's users) thinks about learners (students): https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=learning

Comment: @rwong Well, as I mentioned, there's not much point in trying to explain something in a few comments (or even an answer) here, which usually covers several chapters in a book.

Comment: It is not a bad question. The fact that this has been debated a lot or pondered on by lots of members or is a beginners question is irrelevant. The reason for closure is bogus,  it should have been because it is a duplicate (already has an answer). If no one can find a duplicate,  it is a terrific question and should be reopened. I did take the trouble to Google and found one on SO which was also closed for the wrong reason. I say reopen.

Comment: "They never really explained why you should use an interface" - that's a fair point. Let me try. You'd use an interface (or an abstract class, doesn't really matter) when you want to treat distinct objects in the same way. E.g., you can write a function that does something only with things that fly, but in a generic way - you don't want to know if it's a sparrow, a hawk, or even if it's a bird, so that it can accept things like an airplane or a butterfly. Otherwise, you'd have to write a version for each, and it would mostly be the same. 1/2

Comment: So, what you can do is, you make the function takes a variable with an interface type, that has a method fly (may take some parameters as well), that all of these distinct types support (they implement it). Then you can write the code in a more generalized way that works with any of them. Does that help clear things up a bit? There's more to it than that, but it's too early to explore that right now. That said, the introduction of that interface in the example from your course isn't really well-motivated. (I.e., whether to do it or not in that particular case is a bit of a judgement call) 2/2

Comment: How do I write this method with your solution? `void flyAll(List<Flyable> thingsThatCanFly) {for(Flyable thing : thingsThatCanFly) {thing.fly();}}`

Answer (score 2):

There is a general principle in object oriented programming: Any classes related to animals or vehicles are usually very bad examples that will make you cringe if you read through them in a year or two.

An **interface** in Java defines a set of methods that *any* class might implement or not. If a Java class implements all the methods in the interface, and then declares that it implements the interface (so it didn't just implement methods with the same names by coincidence), then it is said to "support the interface".

Often you have code where some object doesn't really need to belong to some specific class, but needs to implement some method or methods. In that case you can declare that the object doesn't belong to some class, but to an interface - and that means the object could be an instance of *any* class whatsoever that implements the interface. That's usually a good principle, that you make as little requirements as possible.

An abstract class is a class that is intended to be the base class for other class, and where you shouldn't and cannot create instances of the class. Lots of behaviour of the subclasses can be implemented in the abstract class, but there are methods that are declared but not implemented, and you need to implement them in subclasses to be able to use them.

Some people claim that an abstract class is basically the same as an interface. That is wrong. An abstract class is always the base of a class hierarchy, an interface is totally independent of any class hierarchy.

Now the problem with your method "fly": If a class A has a method "fly" and a class B has a method "fly", and they don't belong to some class hierarchy, then the two "fly" methods have the same name, but are different methods. You can't have a variable where you declare "this is either an A instance or a B instance, call the "fly" method". But with an interface, you can. You create a FlyingObject interface with a method "fly". Then both A and B implement the "Fly" method and declare that they are FlyingObject's. And finally you can have a variable of type "FlyingObject interface", with a value that must be *some* object supporting the FlyingObject interface, and you can call the "fly" method of that object.

Comment: Ok, tell me if I've got this right. An interface is a grouping of methods that apply to all objects/classes that fit into that category (Eg anything that can fly should implement an interface called 'Flyable'). An abstract class is a way of organizing your code better by using a hierarchy system in which classes that go together all stem from an abstract class that defines behavior shared by all subclasses. Sort of like taxonomy.